# How to calculate Long Term Average Spectrum of an audio file?

Tags: matlab, audio, frequency-spectrum

I'm working with audio files and I have to find their long term average spectrum. Although I had an option available in the software Praat but I don't understand the algorithm of finding the spectrum. I need to understand it so I know the actual working and also implement it through MATLAB!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a conventional spectral analysis, just do an FFT over your entire  audio file and you obtain an averaged spectrum of the file. A Fourier transform can be viewed as a set of band-pass filters with integration.